# Loop kinetic javascript transitions one after other instead of all at once

Tags: javascript, kineticjs

I want to to queue several transitions one after the other in html5 canvas.
    Looping the transition function calls all the transitions at once. I dont know if   callback will be do this if the iterations are more than 100.
    I want to do something like this:--

for(i=0;i<10;i++)
{
`move(circle,Math.floor(Math.random()*1000),400);`
}

move is my defined function which makes some transitions.its working perfectly fine.

Here, i want the circle to change its postion with every iteration but its changing its position only once.

Comment: If you want to move multiple objects at the same time, you need to calculate each movement and set the position, and draw once, not using transition or animation. If you post your example, it will help to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah ofcource. Its not exactly the solution to the problem but sort of a trick.i first stored the instructions in a separate array (transitionsequence) and used a recursive callback to Callback (the callback defined in kinetic). its not very efficient method but i dont care as long as it solves the problem. :)

`function move2( i , limit) {

```
   var obj = transitionsequence[i].object;
    obj.transitionTo({
      y:100,
      duration: 0.3,
      callback : function()
      {
        obj.transitionTo({
          x:transitionsequence[i].x,
          duration:0.3,
          callback: function()
          {
            obj.transitionTo({
              y:transitionsequence[i].y,
              duration:0.3,
              callback: function()
              {
                if(i < limit)
                move2(i+1 , limit);
              }
            });

          }
        });
      }                          
    });

  };`
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
var i=10;
var interval = window.setInterval(function(){
    move(circle,Math.floor(Math.random()*1000), 400);
    console.log(i);
    if(!--i) {
        window.clearInterval(interval);
    }
}, 400); // wait 400 msecs between calls
```

Or, if your move function was willing to invoke a callback function once the transition was complete :

```
var i=10;
var callback = function(){
    if(i--){
        move(circle,Math.floor(Math.random()*1000),400, callback);
    }
}
callback();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answers, but none of them helped me, Maybe i couldn't explain my problem. 
`
`trans1 = {y:0,x:800,duration:2};`
`trans2 = {y:200,x:0,duration:2};`


`disk[0].transitionTo(trans1);`
`disc[0].transitionTo(trans2);`
`
This code transits the disc directly to (0,200) rather than first moving to (800,0) and then to (0,200).Is there any way i can do that  without using a callback function??

@David McMullin
@unthought

Comment: Javascript is single threaded, it is a terrible idea to try and pause execution waiting for an animation to end, because nothing else could happen for those 200 msecs, no scrolling, no clicking, nothing. As such, yes, you must use a callback / separate function of some sort.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your approach doesn't work is because the browser doesn't get an opportunity to repaint the canvas between your painting steps.  Traditionally this was solved by rendering a single step (frame) and then waiting a small amount of time, but there's a new feature [available in recent browsers: `requestAnimationFrame`](http://caniuse.com/requestanimationframe), which is solving that exact problem.

Check [Animating with javascript: from `setInterval` to `requestAnimationFrame`](http://hacks.mozilla.org/2011/08/animating-with-javascript-from-setinterval-to-requestanimationframe/) and [`requestAnimationFrame` for Smart Animating](http://paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/) (they also show how to create a shim for animating in browsers that don't support `requestAnimationFrame`).

(I don't know kinetic.js, but there might even be direct support for such a shim in it).

Comment: Thanks for you solutions, but none of them actually helped me.
Maybe i couldn't explain my problem.

Comment: @Ankurrana congrats!  It would be great if you could write up your solution as an answer to your question and accept it.